# C++: Can we avoid to systematically specify all the template types?

Tags: c++

I have a template class where the template definition if very long

```
template<typename firstType, typename secondType, typename thirdType, typename fourthType, typename fifthType, typename sixthType>
```

In the .cpp file, writing this entire template in front of each function definition is long and make reading a little difficult. Consider this `set` function

```
template<typename firstType, typename secondType, typename thirdType, typename fourthType, typename fifthType, typename sixthType>
void myClass<firstType, secondType, thirdType, fourthType, fifthType, sixthType>::set(firstType x)
{
   ...
}
```

It would be nice to be able to do

```
TEMPLATEDEFINITIONS
void myClass<MYTEMPLATES>::set(double x)
{
   ...
}
```

instead and the compiler would somehow knows to replace `TEMPLATEDEFINITIONS` and  `MYTEMPLATES` with the appropriate strings. Is something like that possible (without having to `sed` in the makefile)?

Comment: Use a variadic template instead and just constrain the pack size?

Comment: Macros to the rescue! :)

Comment: Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) about putting template code in a cpp file

Comment: You could pull all of those types into a traits class, which would let you write all of your functions like `template <typename TRAITS> void myClass<TRAITS>::set(typename TRAITS::firstType x)`

Comment: Put the definition inside the class directly ?

Comment: Er, I know we don’t like them, but… macros?  Also, why are your template definitions in a `.cpp`?